# Flutter: How to know the key of the widget that triggers an event?

Tags: flutter, widget

How can I to know the `key` value of the widget triggering the `onPressed()` event in Flutter (e.g. for an `IconButton`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach it.

You can make the `key` a global variable if, the IconButton is unique or static (ie you have only a limited known number of IconButton widgets).

Or else you can use `Provider` to access the key in its child tree.

Or you can simply pass the key as a `parameter` to the widget that is called through `onPressed()`.